# Set default value to zero when count is null

Tags: sql, oracle11g

```
 select rd.description||'('||rs.department_code||')' DepartmentName,
              rd.code DepartmentCode,
              rs.description||'('||emv.section_code||')' SectionName,
              emv.section_code SectionCode,
              rsg.description||'('||emv.staff_group_code||')' StaffGroupName,
              emv.staff_group_code StaffGroupCode,
              e.staff_id STAFFID,
              e.surname || ', ' || e.given_name FullName,
              hp.description Position,
              het.description EmploymentType,
              to_char(e.Join_Date, 'dd/MM/yyyy') JoinDate,
              e.employee_no EmployeeNo,
              edt.shift Type,
              to_char(edt.timesheet_date,'Mon') Mth,
              to_char(to_Date(edt.timesheet_date),'mm') MthNum,
              nvl(count(*), 0) Days
        FROM employee e,
            employee_daily_timesheet edt,
            employee_assignment_vw emv,
            ref_section rs,
            ref_department rd,
            hris_position hp,
            hris_employment_type het,
            ref_staffgroup rsg
        WHERE e.employee_no = emv.employee_no
        AND edt.assignment_no = emv.assignment_no
        AND to_char(timesheet_date,'yyyy')=TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('01/31/2015','MM/dd/yyyy'),'yyyy')
        AND  emv.section_code = rs.code
        AND rs.department_code = rd.code
        AND e.position_code = hp.code(+)
        AND e.employment_type_code = het.code(+)
        AND emv.staff_group_code = rsg.code
        AND edt.shift='OFF'
        GROUP BY  rd.description||'('||rs.department_code||')',
                  rd.code,
                  rs.description||'('||emv.section_code||')',
                  emv.section_code,
                  rsg.description||'('||emv.staff_group_code||')',
                  emv.staff_group_code,
                  e.staff_id,
                  e.surname || ', ' || e.given_name,
                  hp.description ,
                  het.description ,
                  to_char(e.Join_Date, 'dd/MM/yyyy') ,
                  e.employee_no,
                  edt.shift,
                  to_char(edt.timesheet_date,'Mon'),
                   to_char(to_Date(edt.timesheet_date),'mm')
```

Im trying to count the days where the Shift is equal to 'OFF', but it doesnt display records when count is zero or when a month doesnt have an 'OFF' shift. How can I set the value to zero when count is null or when the month doesnt have an 'OFF' shift.

Comment: Do you have a table with the different types of Shifts avalible?

Comment: Yes, but OFF is declared in a different table.

Comment: You need to probably use LEFT JOIN and make WHERE into AND

Comment: I would build the query around the table that holds the shift types. In that way you will always have the shift types and then do a left outer join with the count inside a NVL. Then you will always show OFF and zero if non has a worked in the off shift.

Answer (score 1):

I can't understand your query without knowing the data model (and why in 2016 are you using the ancient `(+)` syntax for outer joins?!) but the general principle is simple.  A `group by` query only returns rows for groups that have some data.  For example:

```
select deptno, count(*)
  from emp
 group by deptno;
```

This will only returns rows for departments that have at least one employee.  But you say "I want to see all departments, even if they have no employees".  Well, the EMP table doesn't contain all the departments, but table DEPT does.  So we can use an outer join (I'll use ANSI syntax) like this:

```
select d.deptno, count(e.empno)
  from dept d
       left join emp e on e.deptno = d.deptno
 group by d.deptno;
```

Note that the driving table has changed from EMP, which doesn't have all the deptno values, to DEPT which does.  If there are no employees for deptno=60 then the query will still return a row for that DEPT, thanks to the outer join.

Note also that I have used `count(e.empno)` not `count(*)`, because I am trying to count employees in the department, not rows returned by the query prior to grouping.  If I used `count(*)` then deptno=60 would return a count of 1 (because there is 1 DEPT row with deptno=60, outer joined to 0 EMP rows, resulting in one result).

If you understand this principle and your data model then you should be able to write an analogous query for your case.

Comment: LOL for the ancient (+) syntax